# Calculate a 95% confidence interval and p-value for the change in C-statistic using bootstrap with R

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval, p-value, bootstrap

I am using `boot()` and `boot.ci()` to furnish confidence intervals for the difference in the $c$-statistic (AUC) between models with and without a novel biomarker. My method is below. I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about it.

Here is example data (n = 500, 3 columns: disease status (1/0), covariate (1/0) and biomarker (1-6)):

```
data <- read.table("https://notendur.hi.is/eyb8/dataframe.txt", header=TRUE)
```

Here is a function that returns the difference in $c$-statistic between the models, for use in `boot()`:

```
library(rms)
Cindexdiff <- function(data, indices){
  data <- data[indices,] # select obs. in bootstrap sample
    # C-statistic without the biomarker:
  C1   <- lrm(disease ~ covariate, data=data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)$stats["C"] 
    # C-statistic with the biomarker:
  C2   <- lrm(disease ~ biomarker + covariate, data=data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)$stats["C"] 
  as.numeric(C2-C1) # returns the difference
}
```

And now the 95% CI for the difference in $c$-statistics with bootstrapping (repeated 999 times):

```
library(boot)
set.seed(1)
b <- boot(data, Cindexdiff, 999)
boot.ci(b)
```

Now, I have **a few questions:**

1. Is this a sound method for calculating bootstrap confidence interval for the change in C-statistic?
2. How should I choose which type of confidence interval from `boot.ci()` to use? "Normal" or bias-corrected (BCa)?

Comment: There is good discussion below on why one might not want to do hypothesis testing with the C-index. However, I still would like to know whether my script is correct. Is this the way to bootstrap in R?

Answer (score 4):

The $c$-index is not a good basis for a statistical comparison of competing models; it lacks power for that.  You can use the gold standard likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test or use a special $c$-statistic for paired prediction assessment (R `Hmisc` package `rcorrp.cens` function) that has much more power than the difference of $c$'s.  `rcorrp.cens` asks the question "in random pairs of observations with paired predictions from two models with equal amounts of overfitting is one more more concordant than the other?".  But there is no reason not to use the age-old partial effect test of association.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can agree that statistical significance of including the biomarker is better assessed with the likelihood ratio test. Nevertheless, I would like to report confidence intervals for the difference between the C-statistics with bootstrapping. Any guidance on how to achieve this in R would be very helpful.

**Note** I have removed the third question relating to the p-value for the change in C-statistic.

Comment: The $c$ statistic's precision makes it not a good choice for comparison in that way.

Comment: Perhaps it is so. However, countless reports in medical literature have made extensive use of the C-statistic in this way, often in addition to IDI, NRI and likelihood ratio test. Here is one example, published in NEJM: [link](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1107477). From reviewing the literature, it seems to be a valid approach (used with caution of course), but I am not a statistician. Thank you for your input Harrell, but I really would like help on _how_ to perform such analyses in R and to know whether my calculations are correct or not.

Comment: Don't perform an analysis that we _know_ is suboptimal.  The fact that it has been used countless times in the literature does not predict the probability that it is a good idea.  As the person who developed the $c$-index I've had a fair amount of experience in this area.  Think of $\Delta c$ as comparing two Wilcoxon statistics for A vs. B and A vs. C to compare B vs. C.  No one would do that.  And the inventor of IDI and NRI recently stated he would never use them for statistical tests but would instead use the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic.

Comment: I value your advice. I guess I am a bit too inclined to do hypothesis testing with these statistics, which may not be correct. Perhaps you can point me towards resources which deal with assessing the improvement in model performance. Although I have read many papers providing suggestions by Pencina, Pepe, Cook, Steyerberg and more, I am not entirely convinced which statistical measures I should use. Perhaps not surprising due to the many different (and similar) methods available.

Comment: I would use things that are derived from likelihood or deviance such as generalized $R^2$ along with plotting predicted values for big model vs. predicted values for smaller model.

Comment: Is there a reference somewhere to the rcorrp.cens test?

Comment: http://citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/key/hoe48cla and http://citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/key/Hmisc