# How to calculate the p-value for the change in C-statistic using boot() or boot.ci()?

Tags: r, bootstrap, concordance

I am using boot() and boot.ci() to calculate confidence intervals for the difference in the c
-statistic (AUC) between models with and without a novel biomarker. But I don't know how to calculate the p-value.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What has led you to take a bootstrap approach?

Comment: To calculate the 95% CI of the change of c-index. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104518/calculate-a-95-confidence-interval-and-p-value-for-the-change-in-c-statistic-us/619455?noredirect=1#comment1151898_619455

Comment: $1)$ Why should the confidence interval tell you the p-value? If you are in a more standard setting (say comparing the means of two equal-variance Gaussian distributions) and calculate a confidence interval, you don't get a p-value. (There's a relationship between confidence intervals and p-values, but a p-value does not just drop out of a confidence interval.) $//$ $2)$ You know from the [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104535/247274) that the developer of the $c$-index thinks this is a suboptimal, and you see his suggestions on better ways to proceed.

Comment: You seem to understand the process, but need help implementing the code.

Comment: I disagree with the closure and have voted to reopen. While plenty of code can be written to solve this problem (at least the way I’ve proposed to solve it), the relationship between confidence intervals and hypothesis tests is statistical theory.

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by expressing my skepticism about this for two reasons.

1. [The developer of the $c$-index says that you are using the $c$-index inappropriately.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104518/calculate-a-95-confidence-interval-and-p-value-for-the-change-in-c-statistic-us/104535#104535)
2. I struggle to say the test to which this p-value corresponds or what kind of distribution there is under the null hypothesis.

I would not take lightly either of these concerns. However...

...if you think about t-testing, using the p-value as the $\alpha$-level for a $(1-\alpha)\times 100\%$ confidence interval will result in a confidence interval with one of the endpoints at the null value. As an example, if you run this code in `R`, you will see that the confidence interval has the `null_value` as the upper limit of the confidence interval.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10
null_value <- 0.5
x <- rnorm(N)
test <- t.test(x, mu = null_value)
p <- test$p.value
t.test(x, conf.level = 1 - p)$conf.int
```

The theoretical explanation goes to the mathematical statistics of hypothesis testing (rejection regions and the related fun that you would find in a book like Casella/Berger).

You could flip this around and vary the `conf.level` to calculate the p-value.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10
null_value <- 0.5
x <- rnorm(N)
test <- t.test(x, mu = null_value)
p <- test$p.value
t.test(x, conf.level = 1 - p)$conf.int
ps <- c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001)
for (i in 1:(length(ps))){
  
  print(ps[i])
  print(t.test(x, conf.level = 1 - ps[i])$conf.int[c(1, 2)])
  print("")
}
```

From the printout, you can see that the p-value must be between $0.05$ and $0.01$, which it is. If you need to tighten your estimate of the p-value, you can use finer resolution, such as `ps <- seq(0.01, 0.05, 0.01)` to try the numbers on $[0.01, 0.05]$ every $0.01$. This will tell you that the p-value is between $0.01$ and $0.02$.

(The p-value is $0.0149607$ in my code.)

If I had to calculate a p-value to go along with my bootstrap confidence interval, I would do it this way and calculate the confidence interval using the `boot.ci` like you already are. Just vary the confidence level until you get one of the endpoints sufficiently close to the value hypothesized under the null hypothesis. A quick implementation might go something like below. I used a BCa confidence interval, but you would use whichever of the options you are using to calculate your confidence interval to get the p-value corresponding to that confidence interval.

```r
library(boot)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10
null_value <- 0.5
x <- rnorm(N)
mean_boot <- function(x, i){
  mean(x[i])
}
boot_object <- boot::boot(x, mean_boot, 1000)
ps <- seq(0.001, 0.05, 0.001)
for (i in 1:(length(ps))){
  
  print(boot::boot.ci(boot_object, type = "bca", conf = 1 - ps[i]))
  
}
```

Running this shows the hypothesized value being excluded from the interval at the $99.1\%$-level and excluded at the $99.2\%$ level, which corresponds to a "p-value" (of sorts) between $0.008$ and $0.009$, compared to the $p=0.01496$ from the usual t-test.

Either p-value would correspond to some kind of test of the following.

$$
H_0: \mu = 0.5\\
H_a: \mu \ne 0.5
$$

I would expect your null and alternative hypothesis to be something like either of the following.

$$
H_0: c_1 - c_2 = 0\\
H_a: c_1 - c_2 \ne 0
$$

$$
H_0: \dfrac{c_1}{c_2} = 1\\
H_a: \dfrac{c_1}{c_2} \ne 1
$$

You also might consider one-sided testing to make sure that the difference in $c$-index is due to the complex model being better, keeping in mind the usual caveats. (This would be analogous to an F-test of nested linear models.)

There is plenty of coding you can do to make this process automated and more accurate, but this is the statistical explanation (along with some caveats).

**REFERENCE**

Casella, George, and Roger L. Berger. *Statistical Inference*. Cengage Learning, 2021.